# How to show Google Font in Safari?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, safari, google-font-api

I'm developing a site with WordPress and I'm using Google font. In the functions.php file I entered this function:

```
function load_fonts() {
    wp_register_style('googleFonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400italic,700italic|Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic,300,300italic');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'googleFonts');
}

add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');
```

In the CSS file I wrote:

```
.bbpt h3{
    color:#B3D036;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}
```

This is working fine with Chrome, Mozilla, Opera, Explorer, but not with Safari and iOS devices.
I tried to follow the solutions on the web but with no result. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Be specific about the solutions you have already followed, if possible.

Comment: Try downloading font and converting to TTF. Mac will take this.

Comment: I would like to find out if there is a solution without having to load other files, but simply by changing this function.

Answer (score 0):

What first comes to mind is to insert the following code into the `<head>` block of your HTML doc:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400italic,700italic|Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic,300,300italic' type='text/css'>
```

Alternatively, you could copy and paste the text from [the file itself](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400italic,700italic|Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic,300,300italic) into your CSS doc.

Comment: I avoided to insert it in the header to speed up the site.